# I cannot get Java to to login with x-auth-token

Tags: java, curl

I am running into an issue with converting my curl call to java.  The following call works for me

```
curl -v -X GET --header X-Auth-Token:fc9e123545678899  "https://stage-rest.click2mail.com/molpro/system/productOptions?documentClass=Letter+8.5+x+11"
```

But when I try to convert to java, I get unathorized.  Anything you can see that I am doing wrong?

```
String webPage ="https://stage-rest.click2mail.com/molpro/productOptions/?documentClass=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.documentClass);

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(webPage);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Auth-Token", "fc9e12345678899");
```

Obviously the token key is changed for this example, but any reason the first works and this one does not?

Comment: There may be an exception related to SSL? or some other exception in logs or console?

Comment: You have a slash after `productOptions` in the Java case but not the curl one, does that make a difference? The server may be giving you a redirect, and the extra header may not be passed when fetching the redirected URL.

Comment: Neither should make a difference.  I can login on Java if I set the authentication to basic and use a valid username/pe, so the ssl shouldn't make a difference.  I'm stuck.

Comment: Enable logging in your http call and post the output

Answer (score 0):

After many headaches it was nothing more than an incorrect url in the Java code